# Coverlet does not generate cobertura.xml for MSTest test projects

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, coverlet

I have a solution with multiple test projects (MSTest). I wanna check my code coverage for the entire solution. To do this, I type the following command:

```bash
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" "MySolution.sln" --no-build -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Con
figuration.IncludeDirectory=PathToMyWebApp\bin
```

In every test project, I see `TestResult` folders. Each of them contains a subfolder. All the subfolders are empty.

I tried absolutely the same with another one solution. The difference was the solution had xUnit test projects, not MSTest. And I did not have any problem. All the subfolders contained `cobertura.xml`

I also noticed this error in the console:

```
Could not find data collector 'XPlat Code Coverage"
```

I have checked several sources in the internet (including stackoverflow) where this error was mentioned. But I have not found anything working for me. I tried the following advices:

1. Publish my web project and specify path to the published project. No effect.
2. Install this  `<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.0.1" />`. It did not work also, and I completely do not appreciate this approach, because why should I install anything additionally into my code base if my global configuration worked perfectly for other solutions?

Globally I have installed:

```
coverlet.console 6.0.0
dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool 5.1.23
```

Does somebody have any ideas, why it does not want to work with MSTest? By the way, I tried to add an xUnity test project into this solution (that has MSTest projects). And you know what? The folder `TestResult` had `cobertura.xml`. So, what is wrong with MSTest? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. This thing is compulsory in your `.csproj`:

```
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
```

If you generate a new test project (for example, xUnit project) you will see it added by default.

I hope this information will save somebody's time.